# maxima and minima for a boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maxima-minima, boundary-value-problem, laplacian

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be open and bounded and $u \in C^{2}(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega}).$

Let u be a solution of the following boundary value problem:

$\Delta u = u^3 - u$ $\hspace{3mm}$ in $\Omega$,
$u = \frac{1}{2}$ $\hspace{16mm}$ on $\partial \Omega$.

Show that $-1 \leq u \leq 1$ throughout $\Omega$.

Attempt:

We know that extrema (maxima and minima) exist, since $u \in C^{2}(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ and $\bar{\Omega}, \partial \Omega$ are compact. Assume that there is a (local) maximum of u in $x \in \Omega$. Since $x \in \Omega$ is a (local) maximum of u, we know that $\Delta u(x) \leq 0$. So, then $u(x)^{3} - u(x) \leq 0$. So $u(x)(u(x)^{2} -1) \leq 0$. So $u(x) \leq 0$ and $u(x)^{2} > 1$ ór $u(x) > 0$ and $u(x)^{2} \leq 1$. So $u(x) < -1$ ór $0 < u(x) \leq 1$.

Assume that there is a (local) minimum of u in $y \in \Omega$. Since $y \in \Omega$ is a (local) minimum of u, we know that $\Delta u(y) \geq 0$. So, then $u(y)^{3} - u(y) \geq 0$. So $u(y)(u(y)^{2} -1) \geq 0$. So $u(y) \geq 0$ and $u(y)^{2} \geq 1$ ór $u(y) \leq 0$ and $u(y)^{2} \leq 1$. So $u(y) \geq 1$ ór $-1 \leq u(y) \leq 0$.

How to conclude now that $-1 \leq u \leq 1$ in $\Omega$? So how to derive that those other cases can´t hold. I think we somehow need to use that $u = \frac{1}{2}$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$. But I don´t know why. I think we can´t apply the maximal principle here, since we don´t know if the function u is harmonic, subharmonic or superharmonic.

Maybe it is just logical thinking that we can not have that $u(x) < -1$ holds for the maximum and $u(y) \geq 1$ holds for the minimum. But then we didn´t use the boundary condition ($u = \frac{1}{2}$ on $\partial \Omega$) at all.

In ¨[A priori estimate on this boundary value problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3824975/apriori-estimate-on-this-boundary-value-problem)¨ someone asked almost the same question. But I don´t know how and what kind of weak maximum principle is needed then.

Comment: Another way to solve the problem, multiply your PDE by $u$ and integrate by parts to get $$\int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla u \rvert^{2} dx = \int_{\Omega} u^{2} (1-u^{2}) dx$$ The LHS is non-negative and the RHS is iff $1 - u^{2} \ge 0$.

Comment: It's not clear how you derive $f \ge 0$ from $\int_\Omega f \ge 0$? @mattos

Comment: @ArcticChar The integral of a non-negative function is non-negative, meaning that $$0 \le \int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla u \rvert^{2} dx = \int_{\Omega} u^{2} (1 - u^{2}) dx$$ WLOG, if $\ \forall \epsilon > 0, \ u = 1 + \epsilon > 1$ then $$\int_{\Omega} u^{2} (1-u^{2}) dx = \int_{\Omega} -\epsilon (1+\epsilon)^{2} (2 + \epsilon) dx < 0$$ contradiction.

Comment: Why are you treating u as a constant function? @mattos

Comment: The function u depends on x. But $\Omega$ is bounded and u is continuous on $\Omega$. So I think that you indeed may conclude that $u^{2}(1-u^{2}) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \Omega$. And thus $u^{2} \leq 1$.

Comment: However, I am not completely sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y_m$ and $y_M$ be points in $\overline \Omega$ where $u$ attains the minimum and the maximum respectively. Since $u = 1/2$ on $\partial \Omega$, $u(y_m) \le 1/2 \le u(y_M)$.

Start with the maximum. From your argument, one has
$$ u(y_M ) ^3 - u(y_M) \le 0, $$
since $u(y_M)>0$, this implies $u(y_M) \le 1$.

Now for the minimum, at $y_m$ we have
$$ \tag{1} u(y_m)^3 - u(y_m) \ge 0.$$
Note $u(y_m)$ must be negative: if $u(y_m)\ge 0$, then $u(y_m)^3< u(y_m) $ since $u(y_m) <1$.

Thus $u(y_m)<0$ and (1) imply $u^2 (y_m) \le 1$ which means $u(y_m) \ge -1$. This finishes the proof.